# Rewrite is not running from matched url

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite:

```
rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&other=$3&ajax=0;
```

I thought that this worked before, but it isn't working. So, what I am trying to achieve is to break this out, take this URL for example:

```
/page1/action1/other1/other2/other3
```

I would then like the values to be set to the following php `$_GET` variables:

```
page = page1
action = action1
other = other1/other2/other3
```

But it is skipping that rewrite and going to a different one for some reason. What can I do to make it use that rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

I think nginx includes the leading `/` in the REQUEST_URI, therefore your pattern doesn't match.

Try it with `rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&other=$3&ajax=0;`

(to make sure this has no impact, you could make it optional: `^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$`)